# Java Applet not running despite being added as a trusted site

Tags: java, applet

Quick question here. I am trying to run the Java applet here: http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~lambert/java/3d/hull.html. I have contacted the creator of the site to let him know his applet is untrusted.

However, I followed the instructions here: http://www.java.com/en/download/help/java_blocked.xml and added "http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au" as a trusted site. The applet still won't load, it's still giving me the following prompt:

[image: Application Blocked]

Any ideas? I am running Java version 1.8.0_25.

Comment: Java applets took a massive hit when 1.7 was implemented. They need to be signed by a trusted party. This was because of some fairly serious security breaches that were possible in 1.6. Don't trust it unless its signed or you know for certain what it is and does.

Answer (score 1):

After adding the site to the Exception Site list as documented in [Why are Java applications blocked by your security settings with the latest Java?](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/java_blocked.xml) you may need to **restart** your browser.

After restarting my browser (Firefox 34.0) the applet worked as expected (there was still a security prompt to ignore on the way but the applet now runs).